# Doctrine Native query inside query builder join

Tags: symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I am working on a query on Doctrine 2 (with Symfony 2.8)

I have this query giving me relevant info:

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('ea');
            $qb->join('ea.entity_b', 'eb')
                ->join('ea.entity_c', 'ec')
                ->join('ec.entity_d', 'ed')
                ->join('MainBundle:Entity_E', 'ee','WITH', 'ee.column1 = ea.id')
                ->join('MainBundle:Entity_F', 'ef', 'WITH', 'ea.column1 = ef.id');
```

Now, I need to add extra info to that query, but it comes from a native SQL, something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM DS ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

And make sure that the id of the result from the native query is equal to ef.id

I hope I made any sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you know DQL ?
Similar to SQL but adapted for Doctrine.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html

You can then do queries like :

```
<?php
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u JOIN u.address a WHERE a.city = 'Berlin'");
$users = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: I will have a look, thanks for the suggestion. But I was looking for a solution without DQL or SQL